# How to make mulitple count down clocks?

Tags: javascript, html

This is what I have.

Some people have suggested I should use a `class` instead of an `id` which is true.

On the other hand if I use a class I don't know if `getelementsbyclassname` even works becoz when I tried it. not even one clock pops up when I run my html page.

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to    
var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second    
var x = setInterval(function() {
  // Get todays date and time     
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  // Find the distance between now an the count down date     
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds     
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"     
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
    minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  // If the count down is over, write some text     
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<p Id="demo"></p>
<p Id="demo"></p>
<p Id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You're confusing `id` with `class`. Also... don't `Id`...

Comment: like i recently mentioned Roko when i used class instead of id nothing works at all.

Comment: OK, but than you are one google away regarding: *`JS how to target elements by class`*

Answer (score 3):

When handling elements **by class** you might want to use:

- `Document.getElementsByClassName("selector")` <sup>[*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)</sup>  or
- `ParentNode.querySelectorAll(".selector")` <sup>[*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/querySelectorAll)</sup>

than you need to loop over the returned [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) collection and assign values.

in **ES6** you can use

```
[...myNodeList].forEach( node => {
    /* do something to node */
});
```

in good old JS it would look like:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < myNodeList.length; i++ ) {
   /* do something to myNodeList[i] */
}
```

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to    
var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second    
var x = setInterval(function() {
  // Get todays date and time     
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  // Find the distance between now an the count down date     
  var dif = countDownDate - now;
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds     
  var d = Math.floor(dif / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var h = Math.floor((dif % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var m = Math.floor((dif % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var s = Math.floor((dif % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  
  var formatted = d + "d " + h + "h " + m + "m " + s + "s ";
  // Output the result in an element with class="demo"     
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".demo")].forEach(el => el.innerHTML = dif < 0 ? "EXPIRED" : formatted );
    
  // If the count down is over, stop the interval   
  if (dif < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p class="demo"></p>
<p class="demo"></p>
<p class="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Wow! thank u very much . i wish i was this awesome in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

First, your HTML is invalid, an `id` should be unique. Let's change the items to `class`:

```
<p class="demo"></p>
<p class="demo"></p>
<p class="demo"></p>
```

Second, it is `getElementsByClassName`, not `getelementsbyclassname`. Javascript is case-sensitive.

Now, let's see how one can work with this:

```
var clocks = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
var x = setInterval(function() {
    for (var clockIndex = 0; clockIndex < clocks.length; clockIndex++) {
        //Handle the clock identified by clocks[clockIndex]
        //If the given clock is expired, then continue;
        //If all of them are expired, then clearInterval(x);
    }
}, 1000);
```