# How to make countdown clocks for multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Below is my php code which connects to my database and collects information and echo's it out as a html table. But the only problem is all the count down clocks count down to a single date. Please help me so that each clock counts down towards an individuals graduation date.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "graduation";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, name, date, status FROM student";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Date of Graduation</th><th>Count-Down-Clock</th></tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td>".$row["date"]."</td><th><p class='demo'></p></th></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Below is my javascript code which makes

into a count down clock.

```
<script>



// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

// Get todays date and time
var now = new Date().getTime();

// Find the dif between now an the count down date
var dif = countDownDate - now;

// Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
 var d = Math.floor(dif / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
 var h = Math.floor((dif % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
 var m = Math.floor((dif % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
 var s = Math.floor((dif % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

 var formatted = d + "d " + h + "h " + m + "m " + s + "s ";
// Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".demo")].forEach(el => el.innerHTML = dif < 0 ? "Expired" : formatted);




    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (dif < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);

    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Edit the question so it contains a) the final table HTML, not the completely irrelevant PHP and b) the JavaScript code in a proper format

Comment: You should add a data attribute to p tag with the date as its value from database. Then on java script you have to loop on all p elm with demo class and get the data attr value to consider it as countdown date and sub. it with  today date and set to current elm. This is how you can put diff countdown for all the rows.

Comment: @ChrisG javascript code in its proper format. How do i convert my php code to html becoz it just refused to allow me to upload a pic

Comment: @ChazzPrinceton a) you can upload images perfectly fine b) **NEVER** post code as image c) looking at your table in the browser, press Ctrl+U to see the source. Copy-paste it to your question.

Comment: What happened to your last account? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47961267/383904

Comment: How many accounts do you have? Why did you asked the same question here, though you were appreciated with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47961384/7678788)

Comment: @ChiragJain it's not exactly the same question... But yeah -  I could've improved on the old one - if requested by OP in comments... - probably he forgot the login data for the old one? Who knows?!

Comment: @RokkC.Buljiam The OP himself [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970496/how-to-make-countdown-clocks-for-multiple-elements#comment82911436_47970892) that he broke the rule, I understand that some time there is urgency to sort out the problem, but the problem is related with the same so OP may comment you there. Anyways **OP** you are new and you don't know all rules, np. Try to avoid mukti users. If you want these two accounts to be merged, request for it. Happy coding to both.

Comment: @ChiragJain thanks. Chirag il ask that my gmail account is merged with my live email.

Answer (score 1):

**Problems:**

- `var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();` is hardcoded
- The same HTML result text is used for all `.demo` elements

**Solution:**

In the code where you have `<td>".$row["date"]."</td>` place instead:

```
<td>
    <div data-date='". $row["date"] ."'></div>
</td>
```

JS should than read forEach element `[data-date]` it's own `data-date` value and use it as countdown start; instead of the currently hardcoded `new Date("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();`

Here's an example with the modified JS:

```js
function countDown(el) { // Create a function that recieves the element as argument

  var countDownDate = new Date(el.dataset.date).getTime();

  var x = setInterval(function() {

    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var dif = countDownDate - now;
    var d = Math.floor(dif / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var h = Math.floor((dif % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var m = Math.floor((dif % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var s = Math.floor((dif % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    var formatted = d + "d " + h + "h " + m + "m " + s + "s ";
    // Output the result in the argument element
    el.innerHTML = dif < 0 ? "Expired" : formatted;

    // If the count down is over, stop Intervals
    if (dif < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
    }
  }, 1000);

}

// Init countDown!
[...document.querySelectorAll("[data-date]")].forEach(el => countDown(el));
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      John
    </td>
    <td>
      <div data-date='Oct 20, 2018 12:00:00'></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Peter
    </td>
    <td>
      <div data-date='Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25'></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Woke up this morning and tried to ask this question on my main profile but i was told to wait four days unfortunatly. So i registered with my chazzitup@live email to try get this done. Im now not sure why javascript is a bit complex. I feel like php is limited .

Comment: @ChazzPrinceton PHP in not *limited*, it runs on the server side - If you want something to dynamically update on the client-side here's JS.

Comment: The way you explain my errors. It makes this so much easy to understand. I really need to start fresh on my basics on my javascript to make html pages more dynamic and more appealing to look at. Thank u very much.

Comment: For better learning JavaScript you should have a powerful base in  C language the parent language

Comment: @ChiragJain only a good understanding of the basics of JavaScript is needed (no other languages)